# How to identify if only a certain amount of numbers in an array are consecutive

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I've been making a poker simulator and I've managed to make a function which can identify an array which has consecutive numbers.

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    print(playerHand)
    for i in range(len(playerHand)-1):
        if playerHand[i] != playerHand [i+1] - 1:
            return False
            print(handstrength)
    return True
    print(handstrength)
```

The only problem is that I want the function to identify 5 consecutive numbers in the array when the length of the array is greater than 5. For example: I want the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` to return True but i also want the array `[1,3,4,5,6,7,9]` to return True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning False too soon. Instead, you could keep a running tally of the amount of consecutive numbers you've seen so far, and reset it when you come across a number that breaks the streak.

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    tally = 1
    for i in range(len(playerHand)-1):
        if playerHand[i] != playerHand [i+1] - 1:
            tally = 0
        tally += 1
        if tally >= 5:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you check if numbers are not consecutive and then return false. I think you could better check if numbers are consecutive and if so raise a counter and if not then reset it. That way you know how many numbers are consecutive. If that is 5 or higher you should return True.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working function, you could just process all the 5-card sets in a loop:

```
for i in range(len(values) - 4):
    is_straight = straightCheck(values[i:i+5])
    if is_straight:
        break
print(is_straight)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def straightCheck(playerHand):
    playerHand.sort()
    print(playerHand)
    count = 0;
    for i in range(len(playerHand)-1):
        if playerHand[i] == playerHand [i+1] - 1:
            count += 1
            if count >= 5:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0

    return False
```